# Listen for messages or embeds send from my Discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a listener for whenever my discord bot sends an embed with a specific title, however I'm not sure how to collect or listen for that event.

I'd like to listen for when my discord bot sends an embed with a title of 'Success'. Is there a way to listen for embeds sent from my discord bot?

It would also work if I could listen for when my discord bot sends a plain text message to a channel, just need a way to listen and do something after it collects that message.

Comment: So do you wanted todo a *awaitMessages*?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages), `awaitMessages` is a type of `MessageCollector`

```js
interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                if (collected.hasOwnProperty('title')) {
                   if (collected.title === 'Success!') interaction.followUp('Detected.')
                };
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                interaction.followUp('No messages collected in the time limit.');
            });
```

Since the embed will have property title, check for that property then if the title matches return success.